# Converting Input String to All Capitals while Performing Regex

Tags: java

I am currently working on when a user input a string, then my program will return the search result based on the inputted string. (In this example is "ca")

In the code below, I am only manage to make my program to return all the results which contains lowercase "ca" only.

However, I would like to convert "ca" to all Upper Case while still performing "contains" Regex when returning the search result. Which means, no matter the case is "ca" or "CA", all the results which conatins "CA" will be returned.

May I know how should I modify the code below? Thanks in advance.

```
public boolean matches( courseList p ) 
{ 
  return p.getName().contains("ca");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just change your whole text to lower/upper case:

```java
public boolean matches( courseList p ) 
{ 
  return p.getName().toUpperCase().contains("CA");
}
```

or

```java
public boolean matches( courseList p ) 
{ 
  return p.getName().toLowerCase().contains("ca");
}
```

Comment: Did you try the code above? For example if `p.getName()` contains `"Capital"` then after `.toUpperCase()` it will be `"CAPITAL"`, so contains `"CA"`.

Comment: I tried, but actually what I want is no matter the case inside `contains()` is "ca" or "CA", all the results which contains "CA" will be returned.

For `return p.getName().toUpperCase().contains("CA");` if the case inside `contains()` is "ca" instead, no result will be returned.

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstand. You have a string as a parameter for the `matches()` function. You need to know if that string contains `ca`, `Ca`, `cA` or `CA` (regex independent of case sensitive), correct? if not, give me more information especially with examples.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. For example, no matter it is `.contains("ca");` **or** `.contains("CA");` all the results which contains **both** "CA" and 'ca" will be returned. So how should I modify the line `return p.getName().contains();`?

Comment: So my code works correctly for your case. What I've done, I modified input string to form, in which case-sensitivity no matter. If the whole string is upper-case, method `.contains("CA")` is enough. Note, that I'm not modifying your input - `.toLowerCase()`/`.tuUpperCase()` returns new string.

Comment: For "CA", `return p.getName().toUpperCase().contains("CA");` works correctly. However, for "ca" `return p.getName().toUpperCase().contains("ca");` does not works correctly for me. What I actually want is no matter the case inside `.contains()` is "ca" or "CA", all the results which contains "CA" will be returned. It seems like `return p.getName().toUpperCase().contains("ca");` is not converting "ca" to "CA"

Comment: But why you try to do `return p.getName().toUpperCase().contains("ca");`, it doesn't make sense, it always returns `false`. Your intention is not clear for me.

Comment: My intention is actually no matter inside `.contains()` is "ca" or "CA" or "Ca" or "cA", I would like it to be converted to "CA".

Comment: @AnonymousUser Is the `"CA"` or `"ca"` passed into your method as an argument by any chance? Because if it is a String literal as in your question and all your examples I really do not understand what you are getting at here.

Comment: @OH GOD SPIDERS, actually the argument in `.contains()` is passed into from a user. A user may key in "ca" or "CA" or even "Ca" when they want to do the search in my program. However, all my results are in Upper Case, that's why I need to convert all the argument in `.contains()` into UpperCase so that results will be returned.

Comment: So use `"CA".toLowerCase()`/`"ca".toUpperCase()` too.

Comment: @AnonymousUser You should have said that from the beginning and included that in your code. And as Dudek just said all you have to do in that case is call toUpperCase or toLowerCase on both Strings. eG `p.getName().toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())`.

Comment: I manage to understand this already, thank you both Dudek and OH GOD SPIDERS. ;)